# Elastic Beanstalk deploying files that are in .ebignore / .gitignore

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, drupal

I have a Drupal app that is deployed with Elastic Beanstalk from a Mac machine, using the latest version of the EB CLI. The repository is an ordinary GitLab, AWS CodeCommit is not used.

Unfortunately, if I don't religiously take care of running a `rm -rf vendor` before running `eb deploy`, it commits four files into the archive:

```
1980-01-01 00:00:00 .....           11           11  ./vendor/grasmash/yaml-expander/scenarios/symfony4/tests
1980-01-01 00:00:00 .....            9            9  ./vendor/grasmash/yaml-expander/scenarios/symfony4/src
1980-01-01 00:00:00 .....           11           11  ./vendor/grasmash/yaml-expander/scenarios/symfony2/tests
1980-01-01 00:00:00 .....            9            9  ./vendor/grasmash/yaml-expander/scenarios/symfony2/src
```

As a result, the deploy fails, with this error message in `eb-engine.log`:

```
2022/10/18 10:07:12.498904 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2022/10/18 10:07:12.768789 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2022/10/18 10:07:12.778754 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/vendor/grasmash/yaml-expander/scenarios/symfony2/src: no such file or directory
```

The `.ebignore` file is identical to `.gitignore`, and has a line

```
/vendor
```

so theoretically, `eb deploy` should not have added these four symlinks at all. There are no other files or folders from `vendor` in the archive. The files' UID, GID and modes are identical to other files in `vendor` that do not get end up deployed.

What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem with a Python & Django application where suddenly a file link nested in `node_modules` - which is not being run or used during the deployment process - caused a failure with the same message `no such file or directory` during the deployment.

Based on [the AWS EB CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore), `.gitignore` is not used when `.ebignore` is present. I had the same patterns in both files, so I decided to simply delete the `.ebignore` file and now my application bundle reduced from 327 MB to just 24 MB. And the deploy was successful.

It could be that `.ebignore` interprets the rules slightly differently than `.gitignore`, which could perhaps explain the differences between the `eb deploy` runs.

This doesn't quite answer your question why the`.ebignore` did not work for you, but you could try deleting it, if all you need is already covered by `.gitignore` anyway.

Other than that, maybe your pattern needs to be adjusted, based on an example in [the Git Documentation in chapter 2.2 Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#_ignoring):

```bash
# only ignore the TODO file in the current directory, not subdir/TODO
/TODO
```

So, maybe the correct pattern for your use case is `/vendor/`.